# My PayPal cart upload code was working, but broke last week. Has something changed?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, upload, cart

I built a third party shopping cart for a client. When a customer checks out, the contents of their cart are uploaded to PayPal for payment processing. This had been working for a couple of months, but last week checkout became nonfunctional.

After some debugging I found that the information returned from posting the cart data seemed to have changed. Formerly, the post returned a small message containing a link that can be used to display PayPal's review page:

```
Found. Redirecting to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=#################&useraction=commit&mfid=###########################
```

Now, however, what gets returned looks like the contents of the entire target page before it has been processed. I can sort of display the page in a browser, but it contains many references to PayPal-specific modules that can't be found because they exist at PayPal, not on my system. All I see is a spinner that spins forever.

Here is a simplified version of the code I used to upload the cart and extract the URL for redirection:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

$fields = [
    'cmd' => '_cart',
    'upload' => '1',
    'business' => 'account@domain.com',
    'item_name_1' => 'Pack',
    'amount_1' => '1.00',
    'shipping_1' => '0.09',
];

$query = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$redirectUrl = getRedirectUrl($result);
curl_close($ch);

if ($redirectUrl) {
    $returnArray = ['success' => true,
        'data' => $redirectUrl];
}
else {
    $returnArray = ['success' => false,
        'data' => $result];
}

echo json_encode($returnArray);

function getRedirectUrl($returnedString) {
    $pattern = '/Found\. Redirecting to (.*)$/';
    $matches = [];
    $match = preg_match($pattern, $returnedString, $matches);

    if ($match) {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I would like to find out if something changed at PayPal last week that made this stop working or, barring that, if anyone has a suggestion as to how I might modify this code so that I can post and then open the PayPal review page in a second window.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked Paypal for any changes?

Comment: @PeterM - Is there a direct way to do that? I've been Googling for info for a couple of days, and some of the links are to PayPal developer articles, but I don't have an answer yet.